# Laravel 5.2 query using query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How i do this query using query builder:

```
SELECT code FROM client WHERE code
//                =(SELECT max(code) FROM client where code LIKE '" . $year . "%')";
```

i try this:

```
$row = Client::find(DB::table('client')->max('code'));
```

but return null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
`Client::where('code', 'LIKE', $year . '%')->max('code');`

Comment: @FabioSantos please, tag answer like a Best, if it works.